# ORACLE CONVERT CHAR FORMAT "YYYY-WW" TO DATE FORMAT

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime

I am trying to convert char date format "YYYY-WW" in ORACLE to date for calculating by week in year but have a trouble with error message `format code cannot appear in date input format`

If i write

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1970-01-01 07:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM'),'YYYY-MM')
```

It will be normal

But if i write

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1970-01-01 07:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'),'YYYY-WW'),'YYYY-WW')
```

The message error `format code cannot appear in date input format` appear. I don't have no idea how to convert it right

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Seven dates convert to the same YYYY-WW value; so what date would you expect to get back going the other way? What single date does week 1 of 1970 represent? (You might mean the Sunday or the Monday depending on locale, but Oracle doesn't know that.) Your sample also has a non-midnight time, so are you expecting that to be retained somehow?

Comment: i'm in UTC+7 so that why my sample is not midnight. what i expect is i can convert it for calculate changes of data by week in year or by month because my data is not exactly UTC date format, it's ISO date so i need to convert it for another team understand. But thanks for your advice

Comment: Your question says you're converting from a YYYY-WW string; but are you actually starting with a date, or a YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS string? And what exact result do you want - the start of the week or the start of the ISO week, since you mentioned ISO? (What would today give you - 2022-07-23 or 22-07-25?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
TO_DATE( year || '-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) + INTERVAL '7' DAY * (week - 1)
```

For your code:

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE( TO_CHAR(dt, 'YYYY') || '-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD' )
         + INTERVAL '7' DAY * (TO_CHAR(dt, 'WW') - 1) AS week_start
FROM   (
  SELECT TO_DATE('1970-01-01 07:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS dt
  FROM   DUAL
);
```

---

If you want to use ISO weeks (which always start on a Monday, rather than counting from the 1st January as `WW` does) then:

```sql
TRUNC( TO_DATE( iso_year || '-01-04', 'YYYY-MM-DD' ), 'IW')
  + INTERVAL '7' DAY * (iso_week - 1)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=acd589d7422a1421e3df1faff05a11b3)*

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this for guidance. https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=week-of-year-in-sql-confusing

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built-in way to convert a week number back to a date, as the result would be a bit arbitrary - which of the (up to) seven days in the week should it return?

If you want the first day of the week, as would be found by truncating the original date to WW precision (which is based on the day of the week of the first day of the year - [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#d49931e2660)), then you can reverse that process by getting the first day of the year and then adding the number of days in the specified number of weeks.

To do that you need to split your string into the two component parts:

```
substr('1970-01', 1, 4)
substr('1970-01', 6, 2)
```

and convert the first part to a date:

```
to_date(substr('1970-01', 1, 4) || '-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

and the second part to a number of weeks:

```
to_number(substr('1970-01', 6, 2))
```

then subtract one from that number of weeks, multiply by seven, and add it to the base date:

```
select to_date(substr('1970-01', 1, 4) || '-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  + (7 * (to_number(substr('1970-01', 6, 2)) - 1))
from dual

1970-01-01
```

It's  bit hard to tell that has been adjusted, so trying with today's date, which is week 30 of 2022:

```
select to_date(substr('2022-30', 1, 4) || '-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  + (7 * (to_number(substr('2022-30', 6, 2)) - 1))
from dual

2022-07-23
```

which matches what `trunc(sysdate, 'WW')` gives.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f2fd651cca2213ce15e1a5ce07a60408)

If you want a specific day of the week then you'll need to figure out how much to adjust that, based on what day of the week the first day of the year was.

Answer (score 0):

Select
Extract (year from TO_DATE('1970-01-01 07:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')) || '-' ||
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1970-01-01 07:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'),'WW')
From dual

Comment: If you're starting from a date anyway - not a string as the question title implies - then you can just do `to_char(<date>, 'YYYY-WW')` without the extract or concatenation. But the question is about going the other way, converting a YYYY-WW back to an actual date.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting from a string like '1970-01-01 07:00:00' and want the first day of the corresponding week, you don't need to convert to and from strings and dates repeatedly; you just need to convert that string to a date once, and [truncate it](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TRUNC-date.html):

```
trunc(to_date('1970-01-01 07:00:00'), 'WW')
```

or if you want the ISO week:

```
trunc(to_date('1970-01-01 07:00:00'), 'IW')
```

For your example that would give:

```
select to_date('1970-01-01 07:00:00') as dt,
 trunc(to_date('1970-01-01 07:00:00'), 'WW') as ww,
 trunc(to_date('1970-01-01 07:00:00'), 'IW') as iw
from dual;
```

| DT | WW | IW |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1970-01-01 07:00:00 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | 1969-12-29 00:00:00 |

And for today it would give:

```
select to_date('2022-07-28 07:00:00') as dt,
 trunc(to_date('2022-07-28 07:00:00'), 'WW') as ww,
 trunc(to_date('2022-07-28 07:00:00'), 'IW') as iw
from dual;
```

| DT | WW | IW |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-28 07:00:00 | 2022-07-23 00:00:00 | 2022-07-25 00:00:00 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=56dcaf86818367d479190aa21bebb7fe)